# loadlibrary failed with error 1114

Tags: graphics-card, windows-10, java, opengl, display-driver

Yesterday i upgraded my OS Windows 7 to Windows 10. When i try to run Android project, which created with LibGDX framework, at desktop mode Java throw LoadLibrary error. Run scf scannow command at cmd.exe but everthing is fine at OS. Googled about this error and this can be about video card. I have two video card on my laptop. Intel graphics hd 3000 and amd radeon hd 7450m. Amd had w10 driver but intel not support hd 3000 at Windows 10 platform.

I tried to run Eclipse at windows 7 compatibility mode but not solved problem. When disable intel graphics then Eclipse throw "OpenGL not supported by video card" error.

What can i do? Do i have to restore Windows 7 because of intel graphics support problem?

jdk->version 8 update 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey. I solved problem. Java version occur problem. Java 1.8 version not compatible with intel graphics 3000 on windows 10. For fix problem first download java 1.7 jdk and install your PC and then

1- Right click your desktop project and select properties. 
2- Select `Project Facets` menu from left pane. 
3- Change Java version 1.8 to 1.7. 
4- Select Java Build Path menu from left pane and Libraries tab. 
5- Click JRE System Library and click Edit menu. 
6- Select Installed JREs and click add. 
7- Select Standard VM then click Next. 
8- Select your Java 1.7 home directory and click Finish. 
9- Click OK and Finish and OK.

Problem solved!